# Laravel 8 S3 Storage Issues Retrieving Files

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, heroku, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I've been trying to use S3 storage to store images for my site. The images upload and can be seen in the bucket however I'm having problems when retrieving the images to display in my blade pages.

Currently my saving of the file looks like this:

```
$path = $request->file('coverimg')->store('coverimgs', 's3');
Storage::disk('s3')->setVisibility($path, 'public');

$url = Storage::disk('s3')->url($path);

$project->coverimg = $url;
$project->save();
```

this uploads the file and stores the URL to it, but I think there are some mistakes with the URL as when I use:

```
src="{{ Storage::disk('s3')->response($project->coverimg) }}"
```

To get the images I get

> File not found at path: https:/xyz.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/coverimgs/xyz.png

It took me a while to realise that theres a slash missing after the http:/. And the image was never made public within the bucket. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the / gets escaped.
use the URL helper

```
url($project->coverimg)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that blade uses

```
src="{{ Storage::disk('s3')->response($project->coverimg) }}"
```

which escapes some HTML, including the slash in the URL.

using

```
src="{!! Storage::disk('s3')->response($project->coverimg) !!}"
```

doesn't escape, and gives the full correct path. However, the image is still unviewable due to other issues which cause the s3 bucket to not make the image publicly viewable.